# What is the difference between kubernetes labels node-role.kubernetes.io/master and node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane?

Tags: kubernetes

I am newbie to kubernetes, I see one of my node's role is `control-plane,master`. What is the difference?
is a master node is a node running kube-apiserver?
Then what defined control-plane node?

I am using kubectl 1.20.2(kubeadm also 1.20.2).

Comment: I'm curious to know if there's an answer as well, but I think this is because in older versions, control-plane nodes were called master, so a control-plane is annotated with both roles to be compatible with more older tools (but I'm not sure this is the reason honestly)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The old `node-role.kubernetes.io/master` label and taint key has been deprecated and will be replaced with `node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane` instead, they are both valid during a transition period. Adding them both ensures backward compatibility while also supporting tools using the newer terminology.

The reason for the name change is that The Kubernetes project is moving away from wording that is considered offensive. A new working group [WG Naming](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/tree/master/archive/wg-naming) has been created to track this work, and the word *master* was declared as offensive and the [Recommendation: master -> control plane](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/wg-naming/recommendations/001-master-control-plane.md) has been accepted:

> Within the Kubernetes codebase, the term “master” is often used in
> reference to the kubernetes control plane, either as a whole or to
> some subset of the components within. We recommend control plane to
> refer to the set of components as a whole. We recommend
> context-specific alternatives when talking about individual components
> or the roles they serve.

As part of the Kubernetes eco-system, `kubeadm` complies with this recommendation, more information in [KEP-2067: Rename the kubeadm "master" label and taint](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-cluster-lifecycle/kubeadm/2067-rename-master-label-taint/README.md):

> Kubeadm applies a "node-role" label to its control plane Nodes.
> Currently this label key is node-role.kubernetes.io/master and it
> should be renamed to node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane. Kubeadm
> also uses the same "node-role" as key for a taint it applies on
> control plane Nodes. This taint key should also be renamed to
> "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane".

This is also mentioned in the [Kubernetes v1.20.0 Release notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#urgent-upgrade-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Cluster has always been consisting of nodes. Think of nodes as *machines that host your applications/[micro]services*.

In the old days, cluster was separated into two logical areas:

1. **Masters** or **Master Nodes** - *that is the set of nodes that comprise the Control Plane which manages worker nodes, pods, and basically entire K8s cluster infrastructure*;
2. **Worker Nodes** - *that is the set of nodes, that actually host your application (or application components/microservices, if you wish)*.

According to the [**kubernetes.io** documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-control-plane):

> Master is a legacy term, used as synonym for nodes hosting the control plane. The term is still being used by some provisioning tools, such as kubeadm, and managed services, to label nodes with kubernetes.io/role and control placement of control plane pods.

Another quote [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-control-plane):

> hosts running these components (components of the Control Plane) were **historically** called masters.

Today, the new terminology of the Kubernetes splits these two (Control Plane nodes and Worker Nodes) into:

1. Control Plane components (previously master nodes), and
2. Worker Nodes, that host actual application components.

Last but not the least: Control Plane components (formerly - Master Nodes) are not just Kubernetes API Server, but, mostly, [these](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components) (but not restricted to):

- etcd
- API Server
- Scheduler
- Controller Manager
- Cloud Controller Manager