# kubectl cluster-info why is running on control plane and not master node

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Why kubectl cluster-info is running on **control plane** and not **master node**
And on the control plane it is running on a specific IP Address **https://192.168.49.2:8443**
and not not **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**
Running the following command in terminal:

1. minikube start --driver=docker

> minikube v1.20.0 on Ubuntu 16.04
> ✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration
>   minikube 1.21.0 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.21.0
>   To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

> Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
>   Pulling base image ...
> > gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase...: 358.10 MiB / 358.10 MiB  100.00% 797.51 K
> ❗  minikube was unable to download gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.22, but successfully downloaded kicbase/stable:v0.0.22 as a fallback image
>   Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
>   Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.6 ...
> ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
> ▪ Booting up control plane ...
> ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
>   Verifying Kubernetes components...
> ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
>   Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
>   Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by
> default

2. kubectl cluster-info

> Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.49.2:8443
> KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

> To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Kubernetes project is making an effort to move away from wording that can be considered offensive, with one concrete recommendation being [renaming master to control-plane](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/wg-naming/recommendations/001-master-control-plane.md). In other words `control-plane` and `master` mean essentially the same thing, and the goal is to switch the terminology to use `control-plane` exclusively going forward. (More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186014/what-is-the-difference-between-kubernetes-labels-node-role-kubernetes-io-master/66186779#66186779))

The `kubectl` command is a command line interface that executes on a client (i.e your computer) and interacts with the cluster through the `control-plane`.
The IP address you are seing through `cluster-info` is the IP address through which you reach the control-plane